# Multiple jquery sliders not taking styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a multiple jQuery slider and write custom style for that , in my slider if one slider increases the other sliders should decreases and write custom style for these sliders and its not taking those styles anymore. I wrote custom style like **.slider_class .ui-widget-content {... }** but it takes default style **.ui-widget-content {... }**

```
 drawSlider: function(elementId, sliderMax, sliderVal) {    

  $(".slider_class").each(function() {
  $( this ).empty().slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 0,
        max: sliderMax,
        value: sliderVal,
        step: 100,
     slide: function(event, ui) {
        // Update display to current value
        $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);

    var total = 0;

    $(".slider_class").not(this).each(function() {
        total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
    });

    total += ui.value;
    var max = sliderMax - total;
    // Update each slider
    $(".slider_class").not(this).each(function() {

        var t = $(this),
        value = t.slider("option", "value");
        t.slider("option", "max", max + value)
            .siblings().text(value + '/' + (max + value));
        t.slider('value', value);

                  });
     }
});

});


    // code for dynamically displaying the slider 

    $('#account-wrapper-holder').append('<div class="account-wrapper">' +
                        '<h6>' + aName[j] + ':' + aNum[j] + '</h6>' +
                        '<p><span id="text-tot-allocate-value' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '">Current cash balance: $' + balanceRange[j] + '</span>' +
                        '<span>Total to allocate:<input type="text" id="tot-allocate-value' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '" value="' + balanceRange[j] + '" onchange="s.setValue(parseInt(this.value))"/></span></p>' +
                        '<div class="slider_class" id="slider-' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '"></div>' +
                        '<span class="value">0</span><span class="var-account-total-balance" style="float:right;">$0</span></div>'
                    );

                    _this.drawSlider('slider-' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '', sumOfCurrencyBalances, balanceRange[j]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to presume your markup looks like this,

```
<span class="slider_class ui-widget-content">
   ...
</span>
```

In which case the correct css selector would be

```
.slider_class.ui-widget-content {... }
```

Note the lack of a space.

If this is not the case, post your markup.

Edited [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UD9xK/4/)

Comment: <div id="slider-MyNickName22222222" class="slider_class ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

Comment: @jens, then my answer is correct. Although note that, the .ui-widget-content styling will still apply, your custom styling will take precedence.

Comment: Thanks 4 the reply.The sliders are displaying from a loop satisfying certain conditions.
<div class="account-wrapper"><p><span id="text-tot-allocate-valueMargin87654321">Current cash balance: $1800.00</span><span>Total to allocate:<input type="text" onchange="s.setValue(parseInt(this.value))" value="1800.00" id="tot-allocate-valueMargin87654321"></span></p><div id="slider-Margin87654321" class="slider_class ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div><span class="value">0</span><span style="float: right;" class="var-account-total-balance">$3,200</span></div>

Comment: But in Firebug its shows the default style {.ui-widget-content  } even though in markup it shows <div id="slider-Margin87654321" class="slider_class ui-slider....} Is there something wrong with my markup?

Comment: No, as long as the ui-widget-content class is there the styling will apply. In your custom style, just override all the styles. If this is confusing you, try giving me an example [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show me what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Im sorry this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jenishkottaram/UD9xK/ It contains a lot of loops and the sliders are generating from an array so I can't completely implement it in here

Comment: @jens see the jsfiddle I posted.

Comment: Could you please give me the link

Comment: thanks , that works but one more question, if I change one slider the text box is disparaging. DO you have any clue..